# Volley PATCH request pre-lollipop

Tags: android, android-volley, httpurlconnection, okhttp

I'm currently using volley as my network library (I'm using the last version). 
I currently saw that if a pre-lollipop device make a PATCH request this error happen :

```
 Unknown method 'PATCH'; must be one of [OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, POST, PUT,  DELETE, TRACE]
```

I already saw this link [Error in Volley Patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28314160/error-in-volley-patch) that said to use okhttp to define a new httpstack as transport layer with OkUrlFactory.

The problem is that OkUrlFactory is now deprecated and the docs said to use HttpUrlConnection now, so it's a problem because httpurlconnection not working for patch request with some devices.

Is there another way to perform patch request with volley ?

Answer (score 0):

Following the previous answer
Yes, the OkUrlFactory class is not deprecated.
But since you asked about defining a new HttpStack with OkHttp instead of HurlStack, you can follow this example.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.12.12'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.12.12'
    implementation  'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.12'
}
```

And for the new HttpStack it will look like this:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpStack;
import com.schibsted.scm.nextgenapp.backend.managers.ConfigManager;
import com.schibsted.scm.nextgenapp.config.ConfigContainer;
import com.schibsted.scm.nextgenapp.utils.Utils;

import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.StrictHostnameVerifier;
import org.apache.http.entity.BasicHttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicStatusLine;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Headers;
import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Protocol;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.Response;
import okhttp3.ResponseBody;
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;

/**
 * OkHttp backed {@link com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpStack HttpStack} that does not
 * use okhttp-urlconnection
 */
public class OkHttp3Stack implements HttpStack {

    private SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory;
    public OkHttp3Stack(SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory) {
        this.sslSocketFactory = sslSocketFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public HttpResponse performRequest(com.android.volley.Request<?> request, Map<String, String> additionalHeaders)
            throws IOException, AuthFailureError {

        OkHttpClient.Builder clientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        int timeoutMs = request.getTimeoutMs();
        clientBuilder.hostnameVerifier(new StrictHostnameVerifier());
        clientBuilder.connectTimeout(timeoutMs, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        clientBuilder.readTimeout(timeoutMs, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        clientBuilder.writeTimeout(timeoutMs, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        clientBuilder.addInterceptor(httpInteceptor());
        okhttp3.Request.Builder okHttpRequestBuilder = new okhttp3.Request.Builder();
        okHttpRequestBuilder.url(request.getUrl());
        Map<String, String> headers = request.getHeaders();
        for(final String name : headers.keySet()) {
            okHttpRequestBuilder.addHeader(name, headers.get(name));
        }
        for(final String name : additionalHeaders.keySet()) {
            okHttpRequestBuilder.addHeader(name, additionalHeaders.get(name));
        }

        setConnectionParametersForRequest(okHttpRequestBuilder, request);

        OkHttpClient client = clientBuilder.build();
        okhttp3.Request okHttpRequest = okHttpRequestBuilder.build();
        Call okHttpCall = client.newCall(okHttpRequest);
        Response okHttpResponse = okHttpCall.execute();

        StatusLine responseStatus = new BasicStatusLine(parseProtocol(okHttpResponse.protocol()), okHttpResponse.code(), okHttpResponse.message());
        BasicHttpResponse response = new BasicHttpResponse(responseStatus);
        response.setEntity(entityFromOkHttpResponse(okHttpResponse));

        Headers responseHeaders = okHttpResponse.headers();
        for(int i = 0, len = responseHeaders.size(); i < len; i++) {
            final String name = responseHeaders.name(i), value = responseHeaders.value(i);
            if (name != null) {
                response.addHeader(new BasicHeader(name, value));
            }
        }
        return response;
    }
    @SuppressLint("LogNotTimber")
    private static HttpLoggingInterceptor httpInteceptor() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor(message -> {
            Log.d(
                    "myCustomLogger",
                    message
            );
        });
        logging.setLevel( HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        return logging;
    }

    private static HttpEntity entityFromOkHttpResponse(Response r) throws IOException {
        BasicHttpEntity entity = new BasicHttpEntity();
        ResponseBody body = r.body();
        entity.setContent(body.byteStream());
        if(body.byteStream()==null)
            entity.setContentLength(0);
        else
        entity.setContentLength(body.contentLength());
        entity.setContentEncoding(r.header("Content-Encoding"));
        if (body.contentType() != null) {
            entity.setContentType(body.contentType().type());
        }
        return entity;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private static void setConnectionParametersForRequest(okhttp3.Request.Builder builder, com.android.volley.Request<?> request)
            throws IOException, AuthFailureError {
        switch (request.getMethod()) {
            case Request.Method.DEPRECATED_GET_OR_POST:
                // Ensure backwards compatibility.  Volley assumes a request with a null body is a GET.
                byte[] postBody = request.getBody();
                if (postBody != null) {
                    builder.post(RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(request.getBodyContentType()), postBody));
                }
                break;
            case Request.Method.GET:
                builder.get();
                break;
            case Request.Method.DELETE:
                builder.delete();
                break;
            case Request.Method.POST:
                builder.post(createRequestBody(request));
                break;
            case Request.Method.PUT:
                builder.put(createRequestBody(request));
                break;
            case Request.Method.HEAD:
                builder.head();
                break;
            case Request.Method.OPTIONS:
                builder.method("OPTIONS", null);
                break;
            case Request.Method.TRACE:
                builder.method("TRACE", null);
                break;
            case Request.Method.PATCH:
                builder.patch(createRequestBody(request));
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown method type.");
        }
    }

    private static ProtocolVersion parseProtocol(final Protocol p) {
        switch (p) {
            case HTTP_1_0:
                return new ProtocolVersion("HTTP", 1, 0);
            case HTTP_1_1:
                return new ProtocolVersion("HTTP", 1, 1);
            case SPDY_3:
                return new ProtocolVersion("SPDY", 3, 1);
            case HTTP_2:
                return new ProtocolVersion("HTTP", 2, 0);
        }

        throw new IllegalAccessError("Unkwown protocol");
    }

    private static RequestBody createRequestBody(Request r) throws AuthFailureError {
        final byte[] body = r.getBody();
        if (body == null) {
            return RequestBody.create(null, new byte[0]);
        }

        return RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(r.getBodyContentType()), body);
    }
}
```

This answer is based on this [tweet by Jake Wharton](https://twitter.com/JakeWharton/status/684453117648318466?s=20) and on [the following Gist](https://gist.github.com/bryanstern/4e8f1cb5a8e14c202750), feel free to check it out for other answers. I did a slight modification to the last method to avoid an issue with the Post method when the body is null.

Answer (score -1):

The `OkUrlFactory` class is not deprecated.
Add the following in your dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.7.5'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.8.0'
}
```

Then you can use `OkHttpStack` class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack;
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkUrlFactory;

public class OkHttpStack extends HurlStack {
    private final OkUrlFactory mFactory;

    public OkHttpStack() {
        this(new OkHttpClient());
    }

    public OkHttpStack(OkHttpClient client) {
        if (client == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("Client must not be null.");
        }
        mFactory = new OkUrlFactory(client);
    }

    @Override protected HttpURLConnection createConnection(URL url) throws IOException {
        return mFactory.open(url);
    }
}
```

Then you have to create a Volley RequestQueue as following:
`Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext(),new OkHttpStack()).add(putRequest);`

Comment: OkUrlFactory is deprecated. Is there another alternative?

Comment: Check this [OkHttp 3's API](https://twitter.com/JakeWharton/status/684453117648318466?s=20)